# NATS custom metrics

Tags: nats.io, runatserver

All,
Is anyone aware, how can to get the below custom metrics from NATS.

- connections to core nats subject(consumers, publishers, in/out messages from subjects)
- Connections on streams(consumers, publishers, in/out messages from subjects)
- Slow consumer details.
  Thanks in advance.

The existing endpoints can pull aggregated metrics.